# Why does $g$ and $g(h)$ have the same range?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

I have a problem in my textbook:

Prove that the following property is topological:

Every continuous real-valued function on $X$ is bounded.

The answer to this is:

We know that every real-valued function on $(X,d_X)$ is bounded; suppose that $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are homeomorphic via some homeomorphism $h:(X,d_X)\to (Y,d_Y)$. Then if $g:(Y,d_Y)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, the map $g(h): (X,d_X)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and so must be bounded. Since $g$ and $g(h)$ have the same range, $g$ is bounded.

> I understand everything except why does $g$ and $g(h)$ have the same range?

Comment: Because we have changed the "input": for $g$ is $Y$ while for $g(h)$ it is $X$ but the "output" is always that of $g$.

Comment: Conisder e.g. as $g$ the function $x^2$ on the naturals and as $h$ the function $|x|$ on the integers.

Comment: Because $h$ is surjective. This has nothing to do with topology; it's just an easy set-theoretic fact: If $h:A\to B$ is surjective and $g:B\to C$ is arbitrary, then $g\circ h$ has the same range as $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $y$ in the range of $g$. Then $y=g(y')$ for some $y'\in Y$ and, since $h$ is a bijection, $y'=h(x)$, for some $x\in X$. So, $y=g(h(x))$, and therefore $y$ belongs to the range of $g\circ h$.

And, for any two functions $g$ and $h$ such that the range os $h$ is a subset of the domain of $g$, the range of $g\circ h$ is a subset of the range of $g$.